# FCM Invalid topic name on base64 topic

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I subscribe to a base64 (no padding) topic from my android app I get this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=321, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example/com.example.view.activity.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid topic name: aHR0cDovL3d3dy5iYmMuY28udWsvbmV3cy8
                   does not match the allowed format [a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}
```

The topic name is supposed to pass the given exp so I don't know why I get this exception, also the topic doesn't exist yet. The console confirms that no topics exist yet, but when I send a message to the said topic it appears as completed.From the app I can subscribe to topics like "afsfsfsggg" .

Sending a message from the Admin SDK gives this response but no entries in the console:

```
projects/project-id/messages/5312412342391596688
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a newline character"\n".

```
topic.replace("\n", "");
```